# Do I add the Warlock's “Cantrips Known” number to what I already know each level?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, character-advancement

When I as a Warlock get to level 3, do I still only have 2 cantrips, or do I have 6?

Looking at the table on page 106 of the PHB, will I only have 4 cantrips known from Warlock levels at 20th level? Or do they add onto each other at each level-up?

Answer (score 14):

**You only know 2 at level 3**

The chart shows your total overall cantrips at each level. You are correct that the maximum cantrips you can ever learn from warlock levels is 4. However you can also learn them from multi-classing, feats, and some racial choices.

Comment: So I can only have 4 spell slots ever? So max 4 spells a day?

Comment: @eliminator As a sorcerer your power is from invocations (which give you very powerful versions of your cantrips or abilities that work like spells) rather than a stack of spells like a wizard.

Comment: @Eliminator No.  Warlock spell slots recharge after a short rest, so 4 spell slots per big fight.  Which if you rest twice a day could be 12 slots worth of spells...   Moreover, Hex can be maintained for a really long time fairly early on (3rd lvl spell 8 hours, 5th level 24 hours).  Moreover, many invocations allow at will spells. And Eldritch Blast is the most powerful cantrip in the game.

Comment: @Eliminator There's a big difference between cantrips and spells. You can only have 4 *cantrips* but you'll get a lot more *spell slots*. Cantrips don't get used up but spell slots do.

Comment: @Eliminator You may want to re-read the Warlock section and the general section on magic later in the book. You seem to be misunderstanding how spells and cantrips work in general, and the best medicine for that is re-reading the relevant parts of the PHB.

Answer (score 4):

My initial reading of your question determined that you've added "Cantrips known" and "Spells Known." These are discrete categories. As a stock Warlock, at level 3 you know **2** cantrips. Separately, you know **4** Spells, of either level one or two.

A comment to this Answer suggested you were accumulating the "Cantrips Known" per level (2+2+2=6). In that case, the limitations listed per row are independent from the others, specifying the limits for each Warlock level. You know two Cantrips at level 3, and will be able to know a third at level 4.

To increase your number of cantrips available, you can select the "Book of Ancient Secrets" invocation if you're Pact of the Tome or Mage Initiate if you use the optional Feat rule.